# Update using the table list

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, oracle11g

I am facing an issue while updating 100 tables. Problem is as below:

I have to update 299 columns in 100 tables and for that I have to create one oracle procedure. I have created a table with two columns where I am storing the table name and the columns for e.g.:

```
lookup_table:------
table_name column_name
```

Now what I want to do is pick every row and update the cols based on table name, hence I need to use the table_name and column_name as variables.

Let me know if anyone worked on this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For such dynamic operations, you need to (ab)use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** in **PL/SQL**. In SQL, you cannot use object names **dynamically**, it must be **static**.

I would suggest to do it in **SQL** and prepare the required update statements. Using a good text editor it shouldn't be a difficult task.

But, if you still want to do it in PL/SQL, then you need to first build the sql statements dynamically and then use **`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`**.

For example,

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    var_sql   VARCHAR2(1000);
  3    var_tab   VARCHAR2(10);
  4    var_ename VARCHAR2(10);
  5  BEGIN
  6    var_tab:= 'EMP';
  7    var_sql :='SELECT empno FROM '||var_tab||' WHERE empno=7369';
  8    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var_sql INTO var_ename;
  9    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee name is '||var_ename);
 10  END;
 11  /
Employee name is 7369

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```